# Windows 8 + Chrome and broken mailto links

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

I can't get chrome on windows 8 to open mailto links. They work fine in IE, and they work fine in chrome if the mailto is handled by a website (such as gmail), but I can't get it to work if Outlook is set to handle the uri.

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the standard bug investigation/reporting path:

1. look up a similar issue at http://crbug.com
2. if none is found, file a
   new one at http://new.crbug.com

That said, http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62254 looks much like yours.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain from the description if the problem you're having is the same that I had, but...

If clicking a `mailto:` link is bringing Chrome to the forefront but not actually starting a new message in Gmail, then you probably need to set Gmail as the `mailto` handler within Chrome.

1. Open Chrome's Settings.
2. Click "Show advanced settings".
3. Under "Privacy", click "Content settings".
4. Under "Handlers", click "Manage handlers".
5. For the "mailto" Type, set the combo box to "Gmail".
6. OK, OK, and you're done.

Click a `mailto:` link to try it out.